# Adding a Space Context Condition

Tags: 7

I want to add a condition of what type of space is currently active on the site. Does anyone know of a module that supports this?

I notice that spaces is setting a context for us, but I cannot find the relevant plugin or set the condition up in Context UI.

```
function spaces_set_space($space = NULL) {
  static $active_space;
  if (isset($space)) {
    $active_space = $space;
    if (module_exists('context') && 
        $plugin = context_get_plugin('condition','spaces_type')
        ) {
        $plugin->execute($space);
    }
  }
  return isset($active_space) ? $active_space : FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can figure out the name of the contexts made available from spaces, you can use the condition that is triggered by other active contexts.  I personally have not heard of spaces creating context on their own however.  You may also consider writing your own plugin/module as this is relatively simple to do.  I myself used the path condition files to create the context keywords module(http://drupal.org/project/context_keywords).  You could honestly probably reuse 90% of the code from mine, and just change the part that returns true or false.

Answer (score 1):

That code you posted looks like it would do what you wanted? Maybe you'd be better off filing an issue in the Spaces issue queue rather than here?